# Azure cloud service (classic) scalability option not there

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I am new to azure. I am publishing a azure cloud service to azure using Visual Studio. It is publishing properly but in azure portal, under cloud service (classic) option, i do not find any option to scale it (earlier it used to be there in older version of azure).

My WCF service is running just fine but in azure, i am not able to find on which resources it is running.

Please help

Comment: How does your surrounding code look like? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorial for the portal here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale-portal/)

In the new portal (portal.azure.com)

1. Click your cloud service
2. Select the appropriate slot (production or staging)
3. Click on the cloud service **not the instance of the cloud service**
4. This opens up a new blade that has the scale tile
5. Click on the scale tile

[image]